# SSL cert on cloud-formed Elastic beanstalk

Tags: ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I have an elasticbeanstalk application instanciated by cloudformation, but I want to pass it an ARN for an SSL cert to deploy on its ELB. I know how to do it once the ELB is up, I just can't find any docs or examples of how to set it in the cloudformation template. does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try specify it in OptionSettings of AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application. 
You could try something like that:

```
{
   "Namespace": "aws:elb:loadbalancer",
   "OptionName": "LoadBalancerHTTPSPort",
   "Value": "443"
}

{
   "Namespace": "aws:elb:loadbalancer",
   "OptionName": "SSLCertificateId",
   "Value": "Your certificate ARN"
}
```

I didn't test it, so it is no guarantee that it will work.